# Add and delete table row with pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a table with row count. Currently with the code I have now the row count is not update after delete in the middle row. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621819/row-count-is-not-working-properly-when-i-delet-the-row-in-add-row-javascript) and try to apply on my code but it doesn't work for updating row count.

Here is the snippet that able to add and delete.

```js
function add(addrow){
    var id=document.getElementById('addrow').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var count=id.rows.length;
    var newrow=id.insertRow();
    newrow.innerHTML='<td>'+count+'</td><input type="text" name="textbox"><td></td><td><div onclick="del(this)">Delete</div></td>';
}
function del(btn) {
    var deleterow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    deleterow.parentNode.removeChild(deleterow);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="add('addrow')">Add</button>
<table id="addrow">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last row's id as `max_id`, then assign new row's value to `max_id + 1`.

Pseudo-code:

```js
let last_row = table.rows[table.rows.length] - 1;
let max_id = last_row.id;
// create new_row
new_row.id = max_id + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop over all rows after the removed row and decrement their counts by one.

```js
var id=document.getElementById('addrow').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
function add(addrow){
    var count=id.rows.length;
    var newrow=id.insertRow();
    newrow.innerHTML='<td>'+count+'</td><input type="text" name="textbox"><td></td><td><div onclick="del(this)">Delete</div></td>';
}
function del(btn) {
    var deleterow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var num = +deleterow.querySelector("td").textContent;
    deleterow.parentNode.removeChild(deleterow);
    for(let i = num; i < id.rows.length; i++){
       id.rows[i].querySelector("td").textContent--;
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="add('addrow')">Add</button>
<table id="addrow">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
function add(addrow){
        var id=document.getElementById('addrow').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var count=id.rows.length+1;
        var newrow=id.insertRow();
        newrow.innerHTML='<td>'+count+'</td><input type="text" name="textbox"><td></td><td><div onclick="del(this)">Delete</div></td>';
    }
    
    
    function del(btn) {
        var deleterow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
        deleterow.parentNode.removeChild(deleterow);
        let i = 1;
        Array.from(document.querySelector('tbody').children).map(child =>{
          child.children[0].innerHTML = i;
          i++;
        })
    }
```

```html
    <button type="button" onclick="add('addrow')">Add</button>
    <table id="addrow">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Text</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `No` column of the table when any row is deleted.

Heres' one way of doing it:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const tbody = document.getElementById('addrow').querySelector('tbody');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // add new row in table body
  const newRow = tbody.insertRow();
  // get the length of rows after adding the new row
  const count = tbody.rows.length;

  // add columns in the newly added row
  const newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  newCell.textContent = count;
  const newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  newCell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="textbox">';
  const newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  newCell3.innerHTML = `<button id="del" data-row="${count}">Delete</button>`;
});

// listen for click event on delete button of all the rows
tbody.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('#del')) {
    // delete the row using the value of 'data-row' attribute of the delete button
    tbody.parentElement.deleteRow(e.target.dataset.row);
    updateTableRowCount();
  }
});

// update row count when any row is deleted
function updateTableRowCount() {
  [...tbody.children].forEach((row, idx) => {
    // update 'No' column value
    row.firstElementChild.textContent = idx + 1;
    // update `data-row` attribute of the delete button
    row.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.setAttribute('data-row', idx + 1);
  });
}
```

```html
<button>Add</button>

<table id="addrow">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```